# How to handle response from remote server in Netty?

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, netty, nio

I am struggling for 2 days about how I can read a string response on a Netty client (I am newbie in Netty). The problem is:

- I have to connect to an external server, which host is "api.xxx.xx" and port 8443.
- The server request has its own message protocol (as shown in code - a json formatted array of [, , , , ]).
- The server response looks like similar (json format as well).

Well... When I use normal Java sockets, everything works fine (the corresponding code is commented). But , when I try to use Netty async socket programming nothing happens :( What I am doing wrong?

```html
public class Client
{
    private static final StringDecoder DECODER = new StringDecoder();
    private static final StringEncoder ENCODER = new StringEncoder();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String data = "[\"get\",\"/products/{id}\",{\"$data\":{\"id\":\"561e33873dd9172f64814a3e\"},\"$client\":\"lucas\",\"$key\":\"04pRgDl9H\"}]\n";
        
        /*SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

        Socket socket = factory.createSocket("api.schema.io", 8443);

        System.out.println(socket.isConnected());

        OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output);
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        writer.write("[\"get\",\"/products/{id}\",{\"$data\":{\"id\":\"561e33873dd9172f64814a3e\"},\"$client\":\"lucas\",\"$key\":\"04pRgDl9HNZjCxKmweBM3XO5QqcY127nyVvTbtis\"}]\n");

        writer.flush();

        byte b;
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);

        while((b = input.readByte()) != '\n'){
            bb.put(b);
        }

        // Here I got the right response:
        // {"$links":{"variants":{"url":"/products:variants?parent_id={id}"},"bundle_items":{"links":{"*":{"product":{"url":"/products/{product_id}"}}}},"images":{"links":{"*":{"file":{"links":{"data":{"url":"/:files/{id}/data"}}}}}},"category":{"url":"/categories/{category_id}"},"categories":{"url":"/categories:products?product_id={id}"},"stock":{"url":"/products:stock?parent_id={id}"},"reviews":{"url":"/products:reviews?parent_id={id}"}},"$url":"/products/561e33873dd9172f64814a3e","$collection":"com.products","$data":{"name":"iPhone","price":3200,"sale_price":3599,"type":"standard","bundle":false,"virtual":false,"delivery":"shipment","sku":"12","code":"12334","tax_class":"standard","slug":"iphone","variable":true,"stock_tracking":true,"currency":"BRL","date_created":"2015-10-14T10:50:47.044Z","active":false,"id":"561e33873dd9172f64814a3e"},"$time":4,"$status":200}
        System.out.println(new String(bb.array()));

        input.close();
        writer.close();
        socket.close();*/

        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(workerGroup);
        b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

                ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

                pipeline.addLast(DECODER);
                pipeline.addLast(ENCODER);

                // Here I need to read the response... But the execution not even get here... :(
                pipeline.addLast(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {

                        System.out.println("RESPONSE HAS ARRIVED!");

                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }
                });

            }
        });

        // Start the client.
        Channel c = b.connect("api.schema.io", 8443).sync().channel();

        c.writeAndFlush(data);

        c.closeFuture().sync();

        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();

    }
}
```

Sorry for the noob question. But I've tried everything.

Comment: Have you enabled the logger and checked whether you are receiving the messages or not?

Comment: @Sneh No! I will try it

Comment: you are not using netty here, please visit the documentation page of the Netty project http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html